# Will hashing become vulnerable to quantum computers?

Tags: computational-physics, quantum-mechanics

My knowledge of these subjects is reasonable but limited so please correct anything I say that is wrong.

As I understand a hash, with today's technology, is virtually irreversible.
Also, any good hash algorithm is completely symmetrical, which I believe means there is a 1:1 relationship between any possible input and output.

I do not yet fully understand how a hashing algorithm works so please explain in detail why the answer is yes or no.

My question is, will the immense processing power of quantum computers in the future be able to reverse a hash?

Comment: You misunderstand what a "hash" is. It is not a cipher that tries to encrypt a given text. It can also not have a 1:1 relationship because it maps any input to, say, a 16-digit number. If the input is a PDF file, it must be clear that you cannot represent the entire PDF file by a corresponding 16-digits number: the original text clearly has more information than can be represented in the hash.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function .

Comment: I understand that there would of course be collisions if the inputs could be larger than the output. I do already have a basic knowledge of how hashing works and I did think that hashing was irreversible. The main reason for my question was because I remember from when I was learning about hashing and information would often say thing like "hash function are virtually unbreakable" seeming to imply that with sufficient technology or processing power that the could be broken.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Also consider asking at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

As Wolfgang pointed out, your description seems to conflate hashing with encryption.
Hashing produces a small, fixed size value in a given range. The popular SHA256 uses 256 bits. A "secure" hashing algorithm should make it difficult to do a collision attacks; finding inputs to produce a targeted hash value basically requires guessing.

Breaking a hashing algorithm would mean that we could design the input to produce a given hash value (causing a hash collision), and some of the older and simpler ones have been [broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Broken_hash_functions), even without quantum computing.
Broken hashing functions shouldn't be used for things like checksums or crypto currency anymore, but would continue to work as the hashing algorithm for the `dict` in your Python code just fine.

Having written this I found that the actual question you ask was also posed on the [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44386/are-cryptographic-hash-functions-quantum-secure) stackexchange, and that answer leans no.